# How to retrieve more than 100 search results using Twitter RubyGem

Tags: ruby, api, twitter, rubygems

I am using the Twitter rubygem and my goal is to retrieve all 1500 search results of a search.
Currently:

```
Twitter.search("test", :count => 1500).results.map do |status|
    i = i+1
end
puts i
```

The :count does not seem to matter, it only retrieves 100 tweets at most.
This in itself is weird to me as one page of twitter results should return only 20 tweets.
I couldn't find an official doc (sigh~) and digging in the spec didn't help.
Anyone knows how to "turn pages" with this thing, or tell it to do it by itself?

Thanks

Comment: Twitter's API may be the limiting factor here, not the gem.

Comment: Hmm, twitter's API mentions that it should go up to 1500 tweets, but I'll look into this

Comment: I was mistaken, I mixed up "users/search" with "search/tweets" in the Twitter API, the limit seems to be a hundred for the later and a thousand for the first. It's working as intended =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter's API may be the limiting factor here, not the gem. – Andrew Marshall

I was mistaken, I mixed up "users/search" with "search/tweets" in the Twitter API, the limit seems to be a hundred for the later and a thousand for the first. It's working as intended =)